# Enable Email/Password Identity Provider on GCP via Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, idp

I'm using the [identity_platform_oauth_idp_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_oauth_idp_config) teraform resource to configure some OIDC providers on the Google Identity Platform, which is working as expected.

The Identity Platform also supports `Email/Password` and `Phone` as configurable providers, but I'm not able to find the respective terraform resources nor any documentation regarding these features.

Is it possible to enable the `Email/Password` provider via Terraform?

This would be [how to enable it manually](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/quickstart-email-password#add-provider), but this is of course not an option.

Edit: I've created a ticket on the [terraform-provider-google](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/8288) issue tracker

Comment: I'd like to add to this -- if not via Terraform, is there any way to configure an Email/Password provider programatically?  Maybe with some sort of CLI, or any of the available GCP SDKs in any language?

Comment: @istrupin did you ever find an answer to this? I'm also looking for a way to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it doesn't look like anything exists yet.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone finding this page in the future: It's now possible to enable and configure email, phone number, and anonymous sign-in using the new [`google_identity_platform_project_default_config`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_project_default_config) resource [added in November 2022](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/magic-modules/pull/6679).

Example configuration from the documentation linked above:

```
resource "google_identity_platform_project_default_config" "default" {
    sign_in {
        allow_duplicate_emails = true

        anonymous {
            enabled = true
        }

        email {
            enabled = true
            password_required = false
        }

        phone_number {
            enabled = true
            test_phone_numbers = {
                "+11231231234" = "000000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would one do this for a tenant in multi tenant setup and not at a project level?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Rest Api.

> curl -X PATCH -H "Authorization: Bearer "$ACCESS_TOKEN 
> https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/$PROJECT/config  
> --header 'Accept: application/json'   
> --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  
> --data '{"signIn":{"email":{"enabled":true,"passwordRequired":true},"allowDuplicateEmails":false}}'
>
> --compressed

Comment: The service account must have access token creator permissions.